# How Can I test Violations?

Tags: open-policy-agent

The tests I've stumbled across seem to be a lot of the same ones rehashed.

I'm looking into violations with Gatekeeper.

For example, [this Constraint Template](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/blob/master/demo/agilebank/templates/k8sallowedrepos_template.yaml) policy would test the repo that a container came from:

```
package k8sallowedrepos

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  container := input.review.object.spec.containers[_]
  satisfied := [good | repo = input.parameters.repos[_] ; good = startswith(container.image, repo)]
  not any(satisfied)
  msg := sprintf("container <%v> has an invalid image repo <%v>, allowed repos are %v", [container.name, container.image, input.parameters.repos])
}

violation[{"msg": msg}] {
  container := input.review.object.spec.initContainers[_]
  satisfied := [good | repo = input.parameters.repos[_] ; good = startswith(container.image, repo)]
  not any(satisfied)
  msg := sprintf("container <%v> has an invalid image repo <%v>, allowed repos are %v", [container.name, container.image, input.parameters.repos])
}
```

Where would I look to start testing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing your own templates for OPA Gatekeeper we recommend writing tests for the rules in those templates just like any other rules you write for OPA. In this case, you want to write tests to exercising the deny (i.e., all of the statements in one of the rules matched) and no result (i.e., at least one of statements in both of the rules did not match). We recommend that you use OPA's ability to do test-driven development (TDD) as much as possible.

```
package k8sallowedrepos

test_image_safety_positive {
    count(violation) == 1 with input.parameters.repos as ["hooli.com/"]
        with input.review.object.spec.containers as [
            {"name": "ok", "image": "hooli.com/web"},
            {"name": "bad", "image": "badrepo.com/web"},
        ]
}

test_image_safety_negative {
    count(violation) == 0 with input.parameters.repos as ["hooli.com/"]
        with input.review.object.spec.containers as [
            {"name": "ok", "image": "hooli.com/web"},
        ]
}

test_image_safety_init_container_positive {
    count(violation) == 1 with input.parameters.repos as ["hooli.com/"]
        with input.review.object.spec.initContainers as [
            {"name": "ok", "image": "hooli.com/web"},
            {"name": "bad", "image": "badrepo.com/web"},
        ]
}

test_image_safety_init_container_negative {
    count(violation) == 0 with input.parameters.repos as ["hooli.com/"]
        with input.review.object.spec.initContainers as [
            {"name": "ok", "image": "hooli.com/web"},
        ]
}
```

The pattern we have been following in the OPA Gatekeeper library (WIP) is to include the tests in the same package as rules but in a separate file in the same directory (e.g., src.rego and src_test.rego). Link: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/tree/master/library. Note the ConstraintTemplate YAML file that ultimately loads the rules into the cluster should be treated as a build artifact. Keep the source inside a .rego file on disk (in version control) and then generate the ContsraintTemplate YAML from those files.